# How to invoke a checkbox events on loading a fillable pdf form using ITextSharp?

Tags: c#, itext

I have a fillable pdf form and while creating this pdf form, we have added some javascript in the change events of some text fileds.
After saving the form using c# and open it from a different location, the javascript actions and style does not shown. It shows only after any mouse change event or text change event in the newly created pdf form.

Comment: iText does not include a JavaScript interpreter. Thus, events won't be triggered. Even if it had JavaScript support, most events would not trigger; why should they? There after all is no GUI, so fields don't get or lose focus etc. You could consider adding a JavaScript function triggered by opening the document which in turn triggers change events for all fields.all